# sql - first record if the record is one of a duplicate set

Tags: sql, sql-server

After this SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM ['Duplicate Data$']
    WHERE Name in
    (
        SELECT Name
        FROM ['Duplicate Data$']
        GROUP BY Name
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    )
    ORDER BY Name
```

My table looks like this:

```
    ID | Name
  20215 | A Abbott
  22015 | A Abbott
  11825 | A Albert
  20745 | A Albert
  14109 | A Allan
  19696 | A Allan
  13133 | A Allan
  17311 | A Allen
```

I need to query this table so that the results are returned like:

```
     ID | Name
  20215 | A Abbott
  11825 | A Albert
  13133 | A Allan
```

Comment: How do you define *first*? The one with the smallest ID? The one with the largest ID?

Comment: One with the smallest ID

Comment: In that case "Twinkles" is your little star :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
    SELECT MIN(ID),Name
    FROM ['Duplicate Data$']
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ['Duplicate Data$'] A
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) 
            FROM ['Duplicate Data$'] X 
            WHERE A.NAME = X.NAME)
```

Comment: The requirement was "first record **if the record is one of a duplicate set**".

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function, partitioned by `name`, in a subquery or CTE:

```
create table #t
   (ID int, Name varchar(10));
insert #t values
(  20215, 'A Abbott'),
(  22015, 'A Abbott'),
(  11825, 'A Albert'),
(  20745, 'A Albert'),
(  14109, 'A Allan'),
(  19696, 'A Allan'),
(  13133, 'A Allan'),
(  17311, 'A Allen');


select id, name
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn from #t
) x
where rn = 1;
```

("A Allen" in the last row is a typo, right?)

Comment: No, it is apparently a test case. The result must only contain records that are part of a duplicate set. "A Allen" must therefore be excluded, something your answer fails to do.

Comment: @Twinkles This could very well by the case, but how would **you** know that?? Only OP can answer it.

Comment: I have to admit that I was guessing. But if it was intentional, it was a very good idea.

Comment: @Twinkles Well, judging by his query, if "A Allen" occured multiple times in ['Duplicate Data$'], then there should be multiple rows in final result as well if ID as unique, I believe.